# What does cvc mean in XML Schema (Validation) context?

Tags: xml, xsd

This huge document about XML Schema does not explain what cvc means:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/WD-xmlschema11-1-20070830/#validation_failures

It is obvious that is something like a error code. But would it be acronym for something that is not there (code value constraint???).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eh, CVC stands for "Validation Rule"!

Okay, that doesn't make a lot of sense, and I imagine it started out as something more reasonable like "Content Validation Constraint" back in the days before [the first working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-xmlschema11-1-20040716/).

The main thing is that:

1. By starting all validation rules with `cvc-`, uniqueness is aided by avoiding a clash between the name and one for another rule.
2. It acts as a handy clue to the type of rule, as all validation rules start with `cvc-` and only validation rules start with `cvc-`. Similarly, all schema representation constraints start with `src-` except `schema-reference`.

Comment: Even in the first working draft there is not mention for "Content Validation Constraint". Maybe only Henry Thompson know now. \